# Max and Equality DataSet Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Say i have a table like below, so my goal is to find the max points for the matching games and not ID, however if the points are equivalent such as 1-x-5 and 3-x-5 i want to ignore it from the data set. Can anyone help me thank you!

```
id game point
1    x   5
1    z   4
2    y   6
3    x   5
3    y   5
3    z   8
```

therefore only giving me

```
id game point
2   y    6
3   z    8
```

ive tried some coding below but the data is not correct

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Game, T1.Point
FROM TableName As T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT T2.ID, Min(T2.Point) As MinOfPoint
FROM TableName As T2
GROUP BY T2.ID) As SQ
ON T1.ID=SQ.ID And T1.Point=SQ.MinOfPoint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  It's a little dirty but I think it does the trick.

```
SELECT T3.id, T3.game, T3.point
FROM TableName AS T3
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT T1.game, MAX(T1.Mpoint) AS RPoint
    FROM
        (SELECT game, MAX(point) AS MPoint
        FROM TableName
        GROUP BY game, point
        HAVING COUNT(point) = 1) AS T1
    GROUP BY T1.game) AS T2
ON T2.game = T3.game
   AND T2.RPoint = T3.point;
```

Comment: what's this for anyway?  I know, none of my business..  %-)

Comment: Amazing :) just working on side project im trying to get familiar with access vba as well thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for, if I properly understood what you were trying to accomplish at least.

```
select T1.Game, T1.Point
from (select T1.Game, Max(T1.Point) as MaxPoint from T1 Group By T1.Game) as GroupData inner join T1 on GroupData.Game = T1.Game AND GroupData.MaxPoint = T1.Point 
group by T1.game, T1.point 
having Count(T1.id) = 1;
```

Comment: This did not work. It keeps say 'Game' is not part of the aggregate function

Comment: Oops, when i built the test, the table I was referencing was called Name. I missed changing one of the Name.Game to T1.Game. Try it with the updated query.